# How implement Error decoder for multiple feign clients

Tags: spring-boot, feign

I have multiple feign clients in a Spring Boot application. I am using a Controller Advice for handling custom exceptions for each feign client.

Here my controller advice that handles two custom exceptions (one for each client: client1 and client2):

```
   @ControllerAdvice
    public class ExceptionTranslator implements ProblemHandling {
         @ExceptionHandler
        public ResponseEntity<Problem> handleCustomClient1Exception(CustomException1 ex, NativeWebRequest request) {
            Problem problem = Problem.builder()
                    .title(ex.getTitle())
                    .detail(ex.getMessage())
                    .status(ex.getStatusType())
                    .code(ex.getCode())
                    .build();
            return create(ex, problem, request);
        }
         @ExceptionHandler
        public ResponseEntity<Problem> handleCustomClient2Exception(CustomException2 ex, NativeWebRequest request) {
                Problem problem = Problem.builder()
                        .title(ex.getTitle())
                        .detail(ex.getMessage())
                        .status(ex.getStatusType())
                        .code(ex.getCode())
                        .build();
                return create(ex, problem, request);
            }
        }
```

I have implemented an error decoder for feign client1.

```
public class ClientErrorDecoder implements ErrorDecoder {
    final ObjectMapper mapper;


    public ClientErrorDecoder() {
        this.mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    }

@Override
public Exception decode(String methodKey, Response response) {
    ExceptionDTO exceptionDTO;

    try {
        exceptionDTO = mapper.readValue(response.body().asInputStream(), ExceptionDTO.class);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to process response body.", e);
    }


    return new CustomException1(exceptionDTO.getDetail(), exceptionDTO.getCode(), exceptionDTO.getTitle(), exceptionDTO.getStatus());


}
```

}

I have also configured feign for using that error decoder for that specific client like this:

```
feign:
client:
    config:
        client1:
            errorDecoder: feign.codec.ErrorDecoder.Default
```

My question is: **what is the best approach for handling more than one feign client exceptions? Should I use the same error decoder and treat their responses as a generic exception? Or should I create an error decoder for each feign client?**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Quick Answer**

If you work with different APIs, error responses will not be formatted the same way. Hence handling them separately seems to be the best approach.

**Remarks**

From your example, it seems like you defined a custom `ErrorDecoder` that may 
be not used because you also configured feign to use default error decoder for you client1 in properties file.
Even if you defined a `@Configuration` class somewhere with a bean for your custom `ClientErrorDecoder`, 
[Spring Cloud documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_spring-cloud-feign.html) mentions that configuration properties take precedence over `@Configuration` annotation

> If we create both @Configuration bean and configuration properties,
>   configuration properties will win. It will override @Configuration
>   values. But if you want to change the priority to @Configuration, you
>   can change feign.client.default-to-properties to false.

**Example**

Here is a hypothetical pruned configuration to handle multiple feign clients with different error decoders :

*Client1*:
You tell feign to load beans defined in `CustomFeignConfiguration` class for client1

```
@FeignClient(name = "client1", configuration = {CustomFeignConfiguration.class})
public interface Client1 {...}
```

*Client2*: 
Client2 will use default Feign `ErrorDecoder` because no configuration is specified. (Will throw a `FeignException` on error)

```
@FeignClient(name = "client2")
public interface Client2 {...}
```

*Configuration*: Be carefull here, if you add `@Configuration` to `CustomFeignConfiguration`, then `ClientErrorDecoder` bean will be used **for every loaded feign clients** (depending on your application component scanning behaviour)

```
public class CustomFeignConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public ClientErrorDecoder clientErrorDecoder(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        return new ClientErrorDecoder(objectMapper);
    }
}
```

This configuration could be done with properties file aswell.

**Side remark**

From my point of view, you don't even need controller advice. If you use Spring Web `@ResponseStatus` annotation, you can tell which HTTP status code should be sent back with exception body thrown by your custom `ErrorDecoder`.

**Helpeful resources**

- [Spring Cloud Documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_spring-cloud-feign.html)
- [GitHub issue related to the subject](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-openfeign/issues/72)